# make transition effect in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, transition

i have

```
 \begin{itemize}
      \item ...
      \item ...
      ...
 \end{itemize}
```

I want to insert some transition effect to moving between item , any idea?

Comment: You can use slide transitions in beamer, like dissolve: `transdissolve`. Have a look at "14.3 Slide Transitions" in the beameruserguide for examples and a complete list of transitions. The problem might be finding another pdf viewer than Adobe which can display the transitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) for transition effects.